Find an equivalent infinitesimal of the sequence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n},a_0>2$
Consider the sequence $a_0>2, a_{n+1}=f(a_n),n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$. I need to find $c>0$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n-2}{4^{-n}}=c.
$$
It is clear for me that the sequence is decreasing and bounded $2$. Hence it converges to $a\ge 2$. Since
$$
0\le a_n-2 = f(a_{n-1})-f(2)= f'(c_n)(x_{n-1}-2)\le \frac{1}{4}(x_{n-1}-2)\le...\le \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n(a_0-2)
$$it follows that the limit $a$ is equal with $2$. Above I used the Lagrange's mean value theorem and the monotonicity of $f'$ on the interval $[2,\infty)$.
So it is clear for me why the problem ask to compare $a_n-2$ with $4^n$. How can one deduce the value of $c$? Inspired by another posts, I tried to obtain an explicit formula for $a_n$ using the substitution $a_n=2\cos\alpha_n$. If $a_0$ would have been less then $2$, then this algebraic trick would have worked. How to get an analytic formula for $a_n$?

Your trick works, just replace $\cos \alpha_n$ with $\cosh \alpha_n$

I am not very familiar with $cosh$. I am wondering if there exists a different approach.

We can notice
$a_n - 2 = (a_{n+1})^2 - 4 = (a_{n+1} - 2)(a_{n+1} + 2)$
$a_{n+1} - 2 = (a_{n} - 2)(\frac{1}{a_{n+1} + 2})$
$a_n - 2 = (a_0 -2) * \frac{1}{a_1 + 2}*\frac{1}{a_2 + 2}* \dots *\frac{1}{a_n + 2}$
The sequence is decreasing, and all $a_n > 2$ as you know. So all $a_n + 2 > 4$ and $\frac{4}{a_n + 2} < 1$
$\frac{a_n - 2}{4^{-n}}$ = $4^n(a_n - 2) = (a_0 -2) * \frac{4}{a_1 + 2}*\frac{4}{a_2 + 2}* \dots *\frac{4}{a_n + 2}$
So $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n - 2}{4^{-n}} = c = 0$

Your final conclusion is incorrect. A decreasing positive sequence does not necessarily approach zero.

As suggested in a comment, let $a_n = 2\cosh \alpha_n$.
This is possible as $a_n\geq 2$ for all $n$ (e.g. show it by induction). And because $\cosh$ is an even function, we can assume that $\alpha_n\geq 0$. Then
$$2\cosh(\alpha_{n+1})=a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2\left( 1+\cosh(\alpha_n)\right)}=\sqrt{2 \times 2 \cosh^2\left( \frac {\alpha_n}2 \right)}=2\cosh\left(\frac {\alpha_n}2\right)$$
Thus $\cosh(\alpha_{n+1})=\cosh\left(\frac {\alpha_n}2\right)$, implying that $\alpha_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_n}2=\frac{\alpha_0}{2^n}$, with $\alpha_0 = \text{arccosh}\left(\frac{a_0}2\right)$.
Finally, since for small $x$, $\cosh x = 1 + \frac {x^2}2 + o(x^2)$, $$a_n=2\cosh\left(\frac {\alpha_0}{2^n}\right)=2 + 2^{-2n}\alpha_0^2  + o\left( 2^{-2n}\right)$$
This implies
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{a_n-2}{4^{-n}} = \alpha_0^2=\text{arccosh}^2\left(\frac{a_0}2\right)}$$
Note that in the special case where $a_0=2$, then that formula still holds. It's the case where $\alpha_n=0$ and $a_n=2$ for all $n$.
